# asp mvc dropdown list default value does not bound

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

in controller I have :

```
 ViewBag.ActivityTypeID = new SelectList(activityTypes, "ActivityTypeID","Name"
    ,workFlowDetail.ActivityTypeID);
```

and in view :

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ActivityTypeID,new SelectList(ViewBag.ActivityTypeID,"Value","Text"), String.Empty)    
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ActivityTypeID)
```

The default value which is  (workFlowDetail.ActivityTypeID) does not selected by dropdown in my edit view

how can I do that?
thanks

Comment: @ajokar..just try below answer it will work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Problem generally occurs in MVC because `model.ActivityTypeID` and `ViewBag.ActivityTypeID` have `ActivityTypeID` in common that is why problem occur,just change `Viewbag` name and problem will be resolved..

This will work :-

Controller :

```
ViewBag.ActivityType = new SelectList(activityTypes, "ActivityTypeID","Name"
,workFlowDetail.ActivityTypeID);
```

View :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ActivityTypeID,new SelectList(ViewBag.ActivityType,"Value","Text"), String.Empty)    
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ActivityTypeID)
```

Comment: Please Wait,I will check it.

Comment: @ajokar..i answered as per your question because you are using @Html.DropDownListFor() and i answered that way only i.e with strongly typed view...thankzzz...

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following in your view:

> @Html.DropDownList("ActivityTypeID", ViewBag.ActivityTypeID as SelectList)
>   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.ActivityTypeID)